# Xml reading and Parsing in listview in Android?

Tags: android, xml, listview, xml-parsing

I am doing simple project which gets a xml file from the source (this is a folder in the application called "diagrams"). So there is a button when I launch the applciation. when you click the button it will take me the source "diagrams" folder. In the diagrams folder, there are xml files. When I choose any of them it will parse the xml file and create the listview from the xml file. and I will be able to navigate on the listview like a tree structure. Here is a sample xml file. So this should be seen like this

```
<Prototypes>
<Node>
  <Type>Class</Type>
  <ShapeType>Rectangle</ShapeType>
  <Properties>
    <Property>
      <Type>attributes</Type>
      <View Position="Inside" ShapeType="Transparent"/>
      <Modifiers>
        <Modifier id="0">
          <Type>static</Type>
          <View Bold="false" Italic="true" Prefix="" Suffix="" Underline="false"/>
        </Modifier>
        <Modifier id="1">
          <Type>protected</Type>
          <View Bold="false" Italic="false" Prefix="#" Suffix="" Underline="false"/>
        </Modifier>
        <Modifier id="2">
          <Type>private</Type>
          <View Bold="false" Italic="false" Prefix="-" Suffix="" Underline="false"/>
        </Modifier>
      </Modifiers>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Type>operations</Type>
      <View Position="Inside" ShapeType="Transparent"/>
      <Modifiers>
        <Modifier id="0">
          <Type>static</Type>
          <View Bold="false" Italic="true" Prefix="" Suffix="" Underline="false"/>
        </Modifier>
        <Modifier id="1">
          <Type>protected</Type>
          <View Bold="false" Italic="false" Prefix="#" Suffix="" Underline="false"/>
        </Modifier>
        <Modifier id="2">
          <Type>private</Type>
          <View Bold="false" Italic="false" Prefix="-" Suffix="" Underline="false"/>
        </Modifier>
      </Modifiers>
    </Property>
  </Properties>
</Node>
<Edge>
  <Type>Association</Type>
  <LineStyle>Solid</LineStyle>
  <MinAttachedNodes>2</MinAttachedNodes>
  <MaxAttachedNodes>2</MaxAttachedNodes>
  <Heads>
    <Head Head="Tail" headLabel="from"/>
    <Head Head="V" headLabel="to"/>
  </Heads>
</Edge>
<Edge>
  <Type>Generalization</Type>
  <LineStyle>Dashed</LineStyle>
  <MinAttachedNodes>2</MinAttachedNodes>
  <MaxAttachedNodes>2</MaxAttachedNodes>
  <Heads>
    <Head Head="Tail" headLabel="sub class"/>
    <Head Head="Triangle" headLabel="super class"/>
  </Heads>
</Edge>
</Prototypes> 
<Components>
<Nodes>
  <Node Name="Company" Type="Class" id="1">
    <Position x="129.0" y="52.0"/>
    <Properties>
      <Property>
        <Type>attributes</Type>
        <Element>
          <Value>budget</Value>
        </Element>
        <Element>
          <Value>name</Value>
        </Element>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Type>operations</Type>
        <Element>
          <Value>Company</Value>
        </Element>
        <Element>
          <Value>getDriverQualification</Value>
        </Element>
      </Property>
    </Properties>
  </Node>
  <Node Name="Driver" Type="Class" id="2">
    <Position x="135.0" y="304.0"/>
    <Properties>
      <Property>
        <Type>attributes</Type>
        <Element>
          <Value>name</Value>
        </Element>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Type>operations</Type>
        <Element>
          <Value>getQualification</Value>
        </Element>
      </Property>
    </Properties>
  </Node>
  <Node Name="Vehicle" Type="Class" id="3">
    <Position x="477.0" y="301.0"/>
    <Properties>
      <Property>
        <Type>attributes</Type>
        <Element>
          <Value>registration</Value>
        </Element>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Type>operations</Type>
        <Element>
          <Value>Vehicle</Value>
        </Element>
        <Element>
          <Value>getRegistration</Value>
        </Element>
      </Property>
    </Properties>
  </Node>
  <Node Name="Van" Type="Class" id="4">
    <Position x="381.0" y="519.0"/>
    <Properties>
      <Property>
        <Type>attributes</Type>
        <Element>
          <Value>size</Value>
        </Element>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Type>operations</Type>
        <Element>
          <Value>Van</Value>
        </Element>
      </Property>
    </Properties>
  </Node>
  <Node Name="Car" Type="Class" id="5">
    <Position x="641.0" y="512.0"/>
    <Properties>
      <Property>
        <Type>attributes</Type>
        <Element>
          <Value>fuelType</Value>
        </Element>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Type>operations</Type>
        <Element>
          <Value>Car</Value>
        </Element>
      </Property>
    </Properties>
  </Node>
</Nodes>
<Edges>
  <Edge Name="employs" Type="Association" id="1">
    <Nodes>
      <Node Head="" Label="1" id="1"/>
      <Node Head="V" Label="*" id="2"/>
    </Nodes>
  </Edge>
  <Edge Name="hires" Type="Association" id="2">
    <Nodes>
      <Node Head="" Label="1" id="1"/>
      <Node Head="" Label="*" id="3"/>
    </Nodes>
    <Points>
      <Point id="-1">
        <Position x="524.5" y="83.5"/>
        <Neighbours>1 3</Neighbours>
      </Point>
    </Points>
  </Edge>
  <Edge Name="drives" Type="Association" id="3">
    <Nodes>
      <Node Head="V" Label="*" id="3"/>
      <Node Head="" Label="1" id="2"/>
    </Nodes>
  </Edge>
  <Edge Name="G1" Type="Generalization" id="4">
    <Nodes>
      <Node Head="" Label="" id="4"/>
      <Node Head="Triangle" Label="" id="3"/>
    </Nodes>
  </Edge>
  <Edge Name="G2" Type="Generalization" id="5">
    <Nodes>
      <Node Head="Triangle" Label="" id="3"/>
      <Node Head="" Label="" id="5"/>
    </Nodes>
  </Edge>
</Edges>
</Components>
```

And result should be in the list view like; (this is the part of the result. I haven't defined all the output)

```
•   Class
       ➢    Company
           o    Association
                   •    To Vehicle via hires
                   •    To Driver via  employs
           o    Attributes
                   •    budget
                   •    name
           o    operations
                   •    Company
                   •    getDriverQualification
       ➢    Driver
       ➢    Vehicle
       ➢    Van
       ➢    Car
•   Association
•   Generalization
```

I look for your suggestions. Please all suggestions are welcomed. I am not really looking for the exact code here :) I will be coding this but before I start, I am trying to find what would be the best way of parsing the xml file into a listview.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried SAX Parser? source :http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html

Comment: I have heard that but now I am just trying to find out what would be the best. is there any simple example of using sax parser? and tutorial step by step that explains how to use the api to parse xml into listview? Thanks

Comment: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example